# Subtleties of making a request in Russian

Tags: словоупотребление, значения, выражения, повелительное-наклонение

In my university I was explained various grammatical means of making a request, but find it very difficult to understand their connotations. Your language is so rich and nuanced in this regard.

Let's suppose my boss wants me to quickly slice a fish. Or, alternatively, let's suppose that I get a Russian boyfriend in the future and that he wants me to quickly slice a fish for him.

My question is this: What is the difference between the following grammatical means of making a request, in terms of connotations?

> (1) Возьми нож и быстро нарежь рыбу! (Imperative)
>
> (2) Взяла нож и быстро нарезала рыбу! (Past tense)
>
> (3) Берешь нож и быстро режешь рыбу! (Present tense)
>
> (4) Сейчас ты возьмешь нож и быстро нарежешь рыбу! (Future tense)
>
> (5) Ты бы взяла нож и быстро нарезала рыбу! (Hypothetical mood)
>
> (6) Чтоб взяла нож и быстро нарезала рыбу! (Clause with *чтоб*)
>
> (7) Чтоб быстро рыба была нарезана! (Clause with *чтоб* and passive voice)

To me, Sentences (1)-(7) are just requests to quickly slice the fish, but I feel there must be considerable variations in the connotation, because the grammatical means are very different.

Please help me understand the connotations.

Comment: "various grammatical means of making a request" - what you listed here are orders, not requests. They are all rude (unless said as a joke and both parties understand this is not serious). Joking aside, such orders can be acceptable only in a limited number of specific circumstances - in the army, in a prison, a very angry parent talking to their disobeying child etc. A boyfriend talking like that to a Russian girlfriend is probably talking for the last time in his life :) well, at least, for the last time to this girlfriend. (5) is just weird, so my comment does not apply to it.

Comment: @tum_ : >>(5) is just weird, so my comment does not apply to it<< We were given numerous examples of this form, e.g.: *Ты бы потеплее оделся, на улице мороз.* Precisely what is weird in (5)?

Comment: "Быстро" is odd here, and the exclamation mark. A Russian would most likely say "Ты бы взяла нож да рыбу нарезала (чем сидеть без дела/пока время есть)" but this is more of a suggestion rather than order or request...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Your language is so rich and nuanced in this regard

I guess it's not as much as Japanese. Also, this is quite common in many languages to have fine distinctions between orders, polite requests, etc. Also, as it's usual, the intonation could change really much in this regard.

> (1) Возьми нож и быстро нарежь рыбу! (Imperative)

You could think it as "normal", but it's "the bare norm" which could be sometimes considered aggressive. So it's often advisable "to twist" it a little bit, for example: "Возьми, пожалуйста, нож и порежь быстренько рыбу".

In short, you should normally use the imperative, but, please, don't forget to say "please".

> (2) Взяла нож и быстро нарезала рыбу! (Past tense)

This is rude. Or, at least, too demanding.

> (3) Берешь нож и быстро режешь рыбу! (Present tense)
>
> (4) Сейчас ты возьмешь нож и быстро нарежешь рыбу! (Future tense)

Very pushing mentor tone. The differences are more about specific intonation.

> 5) Ты бы взяла нож и быстро нарезала рыбу! (Hypothetical mood)

In general, hypotheticals are polite but rather formal. (BTW. If your sentence sounds a bit strange that's because you use "hypothetical" alongside with "a bare form", which sounds like a clause, not as a separate sentence). So it suits better "the boss", not "the boyfriend".

> (6) Чтоб взяла нож и быстро нарезала рыбу! (Clause with чтоб)

This is very similar to (2). But while (2) usually stands for "do it now", (6) typically means "do it ASAP".

> (7) Чтоб быстро рыба была нарезана! (Clause with чтоб and passive voice)

Well, passive is a passive. "Get it done ASAP".

Comment: +1 from me for the analysis. Having seen (and participated in) other questions by @Mitsuko I can safely assume that her main interest here is focused on "grammatical forms" alone. So I'll take the liberty to emphasize: the effect of gram.forms in these examples (especially, in spoken language) is negligible compared to factors like the intonation, the facial expression, the voice tone, the relationships between the parties etc. In other words - the context, in the widest possible sense of the word.

Comment: @tum_ : I do not get notifications when you refer to me by using @ in the middle of a comment, not in the beginning. This is just how SE works, I think.

Comment: Great analysis, thanks a lot. It is surprising to me that many of these forms are considered rude or pushy.

Comment: @Mitsuko Hmm, weird. But possible, there are various glitches here... I'm in a worse situation - some people address me as @ turn ;) so I don't get notifications regardless of the position of it.. And some poor user "turn" might be receiving them all and cursing the Latin script...

Comment: If many of these forms are rude and pushy and survived in the language, am I right in understanding that Russians frequently use these forms and are thus often rude and pushy? :) Sorry for such a provocative question, but I just cannot resist asking it, as this question naturally came to my mind. You see, only those forms survive that are used :)

Comment: @tum_ Now you referred to me in the beginning of a comment, and I got a notification. So yes, definitely, the symbol @ works only in the first position of a comment.

Comment: @Mitsuko "I was explained various grammatical means of making a request" - we don't know what exactly you were explained. You might have misunderstood the explanations or they were incorrect. As I said, your examples are not (typical) requests and it's you who made them up - does it mean that Japanese girls are rude and pushy? ) I also **emphasized** for you that it's **not** the grammatical forms that make them rude. Imperative mood with an exclamation mark without even "please" is rude (unless bla-bla-bla goes the long list of conditions/exceptions/disclaimers...) I'm half-asleep now.

Comment: @tum_ : I recall a phrase from a dialogue I had to learn: *Так, взяла себя в руки, и давай всё рассказывай по порядку. Подумаем, что можно сделать.* Was it really rude?! It is the same form as (2)!

Comment: @Mitsuko It could be rude when misused. But nowadays one should first look into a dictionary to know the meaning of the word courtesy. For example, if I have come visiting you and say "А ну-ка, Мицуко, быстро схватила нож и метнулась нарезать мне рыбки. А еще принеси воды попить, а то так есть хочется, что и переночевать негде", in fact, it's exceedingly rude. However, I can simply laugh out loud and be assured that you won't show me the door right after that. Alas, there's no way to find any bon ton on the Earth. Not even in Russia.

Comment: @Mitsuko Do they explain the concept of "**context**" in your university? What exactly is your speciality? Is General Linguistics part of your curriculum? I honestly fail to understand why do you expect the grammatical forms to have the functions they do not have... Are we back to "using exactly Putin's grammatical instruments" again and "если ты будешь есть сашими, то я постепенно заточу нож, о чём я и сказала.."? :)  No, your last example is not rude. It's an attempt of a female friend (or mother) to stop the panic/hysteric of another female (or daughter) and help her. It is patronising but

Comment: but she has a right for it.

Comment: @Mitsuko   [Немного о контексте](http://russkiyyazik.ru/428)  "...В наиболее полное представление о коммуникативном К. входят такие составляющие, как тематическая область дискурса (речи, «погружённой в жизнь»), цели и задачи участников акта коммуникации, характер их взаимоотношений, правила речевого поведения..."  Understanding the crucial importance of the context is a key to mastering a language when it comes to subtleties that you're so much interested in. Considering the grammatical forms alone is like seeing a 2D black&white image of an actual object.

Comment: @tum_ : Sure, the context is important. But I believe that grammatical forms per se also have some meaning, otherwise there would not be any need for such a variaty of grammatical forms. My question was about the influence of the grammatical form on the connotation of a request.

Comment: @Mitsuko "..question was about the influence of the grammatical form on the connotation..." - I understood and gave you my answer in the 1st comment under Matt's analysis: **negligible** compared to other aspects of the language. Simply not worth attention. Not just using the same form but saying exactly the same phrase differently or in a different context changes "the connotations" radically. This, of course, applies to the list of examples in this question. This is not the negation of the importance of grammatical forms, this would be stupid, and not to be viewed as a generalized statement.

Answer (score 1):

For a boss' request, #1 is definitely the most appropriate option.
For a boyfriend's request, "hypothetical mood" might be preferable, but your option (#5) is poorly worded.

```
(1) Возьми нож и быстро нарежь рыбу! (Imperative) - just fine;

(2) Взяла нож и быстро нарезала рыбу! (Past tense) - colloquial and impolite (pushy);

(3) Берешь нож и быстро режешь рыбу! (Present tense) - colloquial, usable when addressing a child, for example;

(4) Сейчас ты возьмешь нож и быстро нарежешь рыбу! (Future tense) - Ok, but less usable than #1. Stresses that we are "shifting gears" from planning to action;

(5) Ты бы взяла нож и быстро нарезала рыбу! (Hypothetical mood) - Ok, but sounds cranky. More positive saying would be like "Вот бы ты взяла нож и нарезала побыстрее рыбу!";

(6) Чтоб взяла нож и быстро нарезала рыбу! (Clause with чтоб) - colloquial and impolite;

(7) Чтоб быстро рыба была нарезана! (Clause with чтоб and passive voice) - impolite, pushy;
```

Also consider inserting "пожалуйста" in the sentences. For example, "Возьми, пожалуйста, нож и быстро нарежь рыбу!" is a polite version of #1, and you probably find it used in most situations.

Answer (score 1):

> (1) Возьми нож и быстро нарежь рыбу! (Imperative)

Firm request or order (ex., from cook to his helper)

> (2) Взяла нож и быстро нарезала рыбу! (Past tense)

order with threatening (you may think of family violence)

> (3) Берешь нож и быстро режешь рыбу! (Present tense)

order + explanation (think of cook teaching newbie)

> (4) Сейчас ты возьмешь нож и быстро нарежешь рыбу! (Future tense)

order with threatening ("Сейчас ты возьмешь нож и быстро нарежешь рыбу! Иначе - неделю без сладкого!")

> (5) Ты бы взяла нож и быстро нарезала рыбу! (Hypothetical mood)

Not-so-polite request. (like "Хватить сидеть в телефоне! Ты бы лучше взяла нож и быстро нарезала рыбу!")

> (6) Чтоб взяла нож и быстро нарезала рыбу! (Clause with чтоб)

Impolite firm request or informal order (ex., from father to daughter)

> (7) Чтоб быстро рыба была нарезана! (Clause with чтоб and passive voice)

Impolite firm request or rude order.